# Save HTML table Data in .csv file without using table id using java script

Tags: getelementbyid, tablename

I am trying to get html table data from [this website](http://www.tutiempo.net/en/Climate/India/IN.html)
  and save it in .csv file but I can't do it by using sahi automation tool and java script coz table id is not given.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: http://www.tutiempo.net/en/Climate/India/IN.html from this site I have to save climate record table in .csv format but table ID is not given

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a table without any attributes which make it unique, you can use relational accessors: http://sahi.co.in/w/browser-accessor-apis
You could e.g. access the table with

```
_table($index, _in($someUniqueElement));
```

Regards
Wormi